# C - Communicating between top and bottom level processes

Tags: c, fork, ipc

Given a program that forks n processes, how can I send a message using a named pipe from the bottom level (leaf) process to the top level process.

I know how to write and read from a named pipe, but I'm unsure how to write to a named pipe as a bottom level process and wait to read it only from the top level process.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pipe pair in the top process and have the bottom process inherit it (automatic). The bottom process can then write to the write end and the top process can read from the read end.

You create a pipe pair with the `pipe` syscall documented at 
http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe .
The documentation provides an example where the child reads and the parent writes. In your case, you'll switch it around.

Inherited fds are counted references to a vnode, so that's why you'll need to close all the write ends in all processes other than the bottom process you want to write from so that the eventual close of the write end in the writer process can generate an end-of-file in the reader.